# Connect to ms-access via odb-orm

Tags: c++, ms-access, odb-orm

I am fairly new to this library, and ORM in general but I have the following question:

Is it possible to connect to a table inside a Microsoft .mdb or .accdb local database via odb-orm (code synthesis)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [their website](http://www.codesynthesis.com/products/odb/features.xhtml), it doesn't support MS Access.